# Is there any way to obfuscate Activity name using Dexguard?

Tags: obfuscation, android-security, dexguard

I am using Dexguard to obfuscate my application, but i was wondering why it is not obfuscating the names of Activity classes.
Is there any way to obfuscates these names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DexGuard won't obfuscate names of activity classes that are exported, because the Android runtime treats them as public API. See [How to obfuscate a class which is referenced in Manifest file using Dexguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380092/how-to-obfuscate-a-class-which-is-referenced-in-manifest-file-using-dexguard).